# Video Playlist from different vendor sources (Anvato/Brightcove)

Tags: brightcove

Is it possible to create a video playlist using videos either from Anvato or Brightcove at the same time?

So far I created playlists from one or the other using their respective docs, but I would like one that takes videos from either.

#### Context:

You have settings to create a video from Brightcove or from Anvato.

Brightcove requires:

- Video Id
- Account Id
- Player Id

Anvato requires:

- Account Id
- Video Id

Using their respective SDKs you can load a video using those settings. But both BC and Anvato provide mechanisms to load a playlist from a *list of Video Ids*.

So to create a BC Playlist you use their docs and use the markup along with your list of Video Ids. Same for Anvato.

But in theory it should be possible to have **one** video player that runs all of the video sources if we could get the straight url to the source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly do this with the Brightcove Player. By default, it assumes you're pulling all of the videos from the Video Cloud catalog, as that's what most people do. However, there is a lower level API that allows you to pass an array of video objects in to the playlist. It's call player.catalog.load().

So if you wanted to merge playlists from Anvato and Brightcove:
1) Call Anvato's API to get the list of video metadata/URLs. 
2) Call catalog.getPlaylist() on the Video Cloud APIs. 
3) Append the data from Anvato to the array you got in #2
4) Pass the merged list into player.catalog.load()

Here's some more info.
http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/brightcove-player/guides/playlist-api.html

Comment: Thanks, worth giving a shot